# How do i make my web browser made in wx.python to parse pages(ex.Google.ro)

Tags: python, parsing, wxpython, wxwidgets

Can somebody help me? please i really need to parse at least google. i need to parse url page.

i've made a web browser and this web browser doesn't parse pages. It's made in wxpython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at BeautifulSoup? http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/